# Advantages to uploading files to /tmp before moving off to permanent storage?

Tags: performance

It seems the common trend in programming when building functionality for handling file uploads is to have the file first uploaded to a temporary directory/folder (e.g. /tmp on Linux).  Once the file is completed, it is moved out of the temporary directory and placed in the specified directory for storage.  Some programming/scripting languages default to having uploads in progress be placed in /tmp, while others don't, yet it seems common practice to explicitly set /tmp as a placeholder directory until the upload completes, at which point it is moved to a separate directory.

What advantage is there to using a temporary "holding" directory to upload content to before moving the file(s) off to another partition/directory for long term storage?

I work in an environment where (in-house) network storage is mounted via NFS mounts to virtual machines for persistent storage of large amounts of data (terabytes).  As technology progresses, we're able to ingest data more rapidly, and in much more significant quantities.  Several years ago, it was a simple HTTP upload of one file at a time (of relatively small size, megabytes?), then we went to Flash uploads.  Now we have drag and drop uploads, even with the potential of uploading a file/folder structure in some browsers, in the realm of gigabytes.  It's getting to the point where one user could easily exceed the partition set aside for /tmp if they really want to upload enough at once.  What would be the advantage of expanding /tmp versus just having it directly sent off to the file server, aside from network latency through the NFS mount?  Is this a legacy (now bad-) practice that has grown outdated now that technology is allowing for us to ingest quantities of data that were otherwise inconceivable a decade ago?

Comment: Extracting files from posted data often occurs before logic controlling where the file should be stored is executed (for example, in PHP apps).

Comment: if the computer crashes then the user's space isn't cluttered with half finished files and the move can be atomic depending on the file system

Answer (score 3):

1. Is it for performance in the event the specified storage directory is network storage?

   - Yes, it can be, although not usually.  The performance of the actual upload is rarely the code's primary performance concern.
2. Does Linux routinely scan [its] /tmp directory to delete out old files, saving the developer/administrator for having to account for that elsewhere?

   - Yes, typically.  This also covers the case where the upload-manager process crashes and leaves behind a partial file that wouldn't otherwise be cleaned up.
3. Is it just that way because it is?

   - Yes.  :-)
4. If given the opportunity to simply write the file to the directory it ultimately will get stored off in (e.g. using node.js's fs module), should I, or is this a no-no?

   - There are good reasons for using a temporary-staging directory, and also for locating it on the same filesystem as the target directory.  Many applications put this directory in the same file tree as the eventual target directory, so the eventual "move" operation will be nearly instantaneous (and potentially atomic).  Thus you'll often see things like `/var/spool/myapp/tmp` and `/var/spool/myapp/data`.  But then the application often adds a `cron` task to clean up old files in `.../tmp`.

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on what else is on the system and how things are being used.

On some systems, `/tmp` is commonly used for system files or swap space.  If you fill up `/tmp` on Solaris, [bad things happen](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1075/msgs-2242/index.html) ([and related anecdote](http://nilesh-joshi.blogspot.com/2010/03/tmp-file-system-full-swap-space-limit.html)).  In such a case, if someone uploads a file that fills up this volume, it can crash your system.  Other things that can happen are certain applications won't be able to write their own temp files.

In days of old, you could reasonably trust people not to be stupid (at least outside of September) and malice was reasonably low too.  Today... thats a different story.

The *advantage* to writing to `/tmp` is that it was guaranteed to be a local file system on the machine, present, and patrolled (scripts that would go around and delete old files automatically).  Systems *needed* a `/tmp` to boot and fast access to this was necessary for reasonable performance on the system. Thus, you want to write a file quickly somewhere and then move it off?  Put it in `/tmp`.

With that bit about bad things happening when `/tmp` is full, one should look at other alternatives that provide the same advantage - like making a partition that is mounted to upload files to that won't crash the machine when things are full.

Another consideration though is that 'fast' bit.  Drives have gotten faster since the days of old.  Quite a bit faster - a nice SSD can blow away anything from back then... but do you *really* need an SSD for writing upload files to?  Not only have dives gotten faster, but the network has gotten faster.  Writing upload files to a network storage area can aide in the single point where you can have multiple systems uploading their files to a central spot where other processes can then take up the responsibility of scanning and moving them to the proper location.

So... to summarize:

- Had advantages in days of old

  - faster than network, always there
- Could cause problems
- Days of old are no longer here

  - Drives and networks faster
  - People are stupid and more attackers

So, I'd say no... don't write to `/tmp` anymore as a default answer.  Check with your system administrator about the proper place to write them to that fits their disk use policy and consider writing them to someplace completely off the local system.

Answer (score 1):

`/tmp` is just a convenient spot to put files, and somewhere that you can be fairly confident will be cleaned up (if, for example, the web app failed to do so). So its a reasonable default.

If you do have the option of specifying your own path to upload the files to, there is a good reason to make it a path on the same mount as the ultimate destination, as then you can use an atomic rename to put it in its final place. (If its cross-mount, you need to do a copy).

I wouldn't upload it to its final destination, as (for example) if the upload was aborted in the middle, you could be left with a partial file there. Or if your script dies, you could be left with an orphaned file that isn't referenced by your database.

BTW: Remember that the file name supplied by the client is untrusted data. A malicious user could easily give you the file name `../../../something`, and if you aren't careful, you could wind up writing to something you don't intend to.